# Tengo este error al agregar estas librerias en el pom.xml en eclipse, como puedo solucionarlo

Tags: java

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'dependency'.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que te falta es que este dentro de esto<dependencies> </dependencies>

Comment: lo hice pero me sigue apareciendo el error

Comment: puedes actualizar la pregunta para ver como te quedo

Comment: pon el xml en lugar de la imagen sera mas facil ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

tús dependencias deben ir dentro de los tags  < dependencies >< /dependencies >.
Ejemplo

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <version>2.6</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
   <scope>compile</scope>
   <version>3.2.1</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```